Firebase onsnapshot cost to obtain 3 documents among 1000+ documents?
I want to order by rating among all of the 1000+ users in my snapshot listener, and take the highest 3 of the results. I don't know if it will be a plus to use limit() here. The docs are not clear enough to understand the costs. My code to fetch is:
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(query(collection(db, "users"), where("city", "==", user.city), orderBy("rating", "desc")) ), 
(snapshot) => {....}

In this situation, how many read/write operations will I be charged for? Will it be 1000 or 3? Also, the second question is, what is the most cost-effective way to do this? If I need to obtain best 3 rating users, should I exactly have to make read operations for all 1000 documents and get charged for 1000 reads? I am trying to find a clear answer to this.

There are only costs for the documents that are actually returned to the client. When you use limit(), it is never returning any more documents than that limit.

@DougStevenson Is that mean, if I order and limit by 3, then 3 read operations will be charged?

If your request returns 3 documents, you'll be charged 3 document reads. To remember/understand this it helps to know that Firestore doesn't actually read those other 997 document, as it already disqualifies them from the information in the index that uses to fulfill the query. --- The only exception to this is for queries that contain inequality operations/conditions on multiple fields (where the charge may be slightly higher), but that doesn't apply to the query you shared.

@FrankvanPuffelen Thanks a lot Frank, now I totally understood it
